# Parsing a file line by line for key character in string and copying line

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, sed, awk

I'm trying to parse a DNA protein file. I want to extract just certain amount of information.  I want to parse only if the line starts with "ATOM" and has either G,A,T,C at then end of the fourth column. For example in the snippet below DG would be parsed because it has a G at the end.  Then save the line in file. I am using bash. What would you use to do this?  grep, find, sed, awk or some kind of regular expression?

Thanks for any help!

```
    HETATM  103 HG22 MVA A   8       4.999  -1.260   2.090  1.00  0.00           H            
    HETATM  104 HG23 MVA A   8       5.639  -2.810   2.604  1.00  0.00          H  
    TER     105      MVA A   8                                                      
    ATOM    106  O5'  DG C  11     -12.710   1.571 -11.945  1.00  0.00           O  
    ATOM    107  C5'  DG C  11     -13.491   2.438 -11.111  1.00  0.00           C
```

Additional to the original problem:

Count the lines total and individual G,A,T,C? Output the counted total into a file as Total Lines, TOTAL G, TOTAL T, TOTAL A, TOTAL C.

Comment: how do you put code in comments??

Comment: #!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
count=0
while read LINE
do
       let count++
#       echo "$count $LINE"

VARIABLE="COMPND DNA"
VARIABLEDNA="DNA"
# This is for regular expressions:
if echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$VARIABLEDNA"; then
while read LINE
do
if echo `expr match "$LINE" '\(.[D]*[A].\)' then
echo 'match'
done
break



echo "$count $LINE"

fi


done <$FILENAME

echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"

#done <$FILENAME

Comment: By any means I don't need to work off my code.  I need to use bash though.  I think my expression is not right for finding the DNA chain.  I can parse each line and find ATOM but after I find the line "ATOM" How do I find G,C,A,T at end of a word that is four away from the beginning of the line.

Comment: same question on superuser: http://superuser.com/q/720655/4714

Comment: I didn't get an answer at SuperUSer and since there is discussion here, I close it.

Comment: You should post code up in your question where you can format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I get the chance to answer it, because OP questioned on Kent's answer. Here is question:

```
If you notice Line 3 of the example the 3rd column is blank will this matter, it shouldn't in this case because its not an ATOM but if it was?
```

So the fix is here, (base on the format and location is not changed.

```
awk '/^ATOM/&&substr($0,20,1)~/[GATC]/'  file
```

Test result:

```
$ cat file
HETATM  103 HG22 MVA A   8       4.999  -1.260   2.090  1.00  0.00           H
HETATM  104 HG23 MVA A   8       5.639  -2.810   2.604  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM    105      MVA X   8
ATOM    106  O5'  DG C  11     -12.710   1.571 -11.945  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM    107  C5'  DG C  11     -13.491   2.438 -11.111  1.00  0.00           C

$ awk '/^ATOM/&&substr($0,20,1)~/[GATC]/'  file
ATOM    105      MVA X   8
ATOM    106  O5'  DG C  11     -12.710   1.571 -11.945  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM    107  C5'  DG C  11     -13.491   2.438 -11.111  1.00  0.00           C
```

#### Edit for new request.

```
awk '/^ATOM/&&substr($0,20,1)~/[GATC]/{print;l++;a[substr($0,20,1)]++}END{printf "total line : %s\n",l;for (i in a) printf "%s : %s \n",i,a[i]}'  file

ATOM    105      MVA A   8
ATOM    106  O5'  DG C  11     -12.710   1.571 -11.945  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM    107  C5'  DG C  11     -13.491   2.438 -11.111  1.00  0.00           C
total line : 3
A : 1
G : 2
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution. Thank you.  Is there a way to count the lines for each letter that is copied? For example above 2 lines for G and 1 line for A. If thats to hard just a total.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Could update your request in your question, and provide your export output.

Comment: I updated it. A loop with a counter you can count, keep a total but with awk, how do you tap into that iteration?

Comment: Thank you! Wow, it is really a language. Can I use a[i] and save that to list of arrays or something that I can get access to afterwards?  Being able to get to that information for other purpose is useful.  I'm using this command in loop to do same thing for each file.  Each file will have these stats so if the info is put into some kind of list, vector or array where I can access and iterate later would be useful. How would I got about that?  If I have to I will do all my work right after this statement in the loop?

Comment: Happy to help you, you need vote or accept it for thanks. If you need any new statement, I recommend to start a new topic.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '/^ATOM/&&$4~/[GATC]$/' input > output
```

Comment: Before I finished reading the question, I see a great short answer. So yea, crap! `:)`.

Comment: That looks beautiful...I will report back in little with results. Thank you.  Could you explain it a little so I can learn it? Can I  use awk in bash with no problems?

Comment: @Kent, wouldn't this match strings like `GAP`, `ATM`, etc? I'm just curious.

Comment: @l'L'l it took me sometime to find out the 1st letter in your username is `1 or I or l`... ;-) `[ABC]` means **single** char, `A or B or C` and put `$` at the end, means the last char of that field must be `G or A or T....`

Comment: @Kent, Yes I'd love to see the regex you came up with to figure what the first letter of my name was! :D Regarding the `$`, it's a nice way of terminating a pattern I can now see — thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: +1 but to be honest I don't understand why this wasn't the one and only screamingly obvious solution that immediately occurred to everyone. I mean it's the simple, direct translation of the requirements to code. Did the question change after being posted?

Comment: @EdMorton Not really. Kent used his telepathic power to answer the question as soon as it was submitted. I didn't even get a chance to crack my knuckles, so ended up posting a lousy err old fashioned `bash` solution. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal telepathic power...... I wish I had that... when I open this page, the question was submitted about 7 or 9 mins ago.

Comment: @Kent Err I em e slo reeder!!

Comment: Can I use this in bash? If you notice Line 3 of the example the 3rd column is blank will this matter, it shouldn't in this case because its not an ATOM but if it was?

Comment: @MAXGEN if the delimiter is `<tab>` it is easier if there are spaces in your data.

Comment: Is there a way to count the lines for each letter that is copied?

Comment: @MAXGEN I didn't get you... :(

Comment: When awk goes through the file, is there way to keep track of the total lines that meet the requirement? And individually for ACGT?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an old fashion `bash` way:

```
while read -ra fld; do 
  [[ ${fld[0]} == "ATOM" ]] && [[ ${fld[3]} =~ [GATC]$ ]] && echo "${fld[@]}"
done < dnafile.old > dnafile.new
```

Comment: What does " -ra fld" mean in while read? Is that like reading "while read LINE"?  Also dnafile.old and dnafile.new can I set them to arguments like this " dnafile.old= $1; dnafile.new=$2 "?

Comment: @MAXGEN `-r` stands for `raw input`. It prevents interpretation of backslash escapes and `-a` read the data word-wise into the specified array, in our case `fld`. You then compare first element of array to `ATOM` and look for 4th element for ending with `[GATC]$`. Arrays are indexed at `0` so our first element is `${fld[0]}`. Yes, you can assign filename to variables and your them instead.

Comment: How each line get into it then?  I still need a "while read LINE; do" before?

Comment: k I'm not sure .old and .new are, if that's just pseudo code but I change it for arguments on execution command and it worked very well.  I have results which seems at the moment to be right.  I thank you.  I'm using your answer because you said its bash.  Are the other answers not compatible in bash? I have to parse bigger set of files so am I looking at very efficient way of doing it?  Is there anything in bash I can look into to be more efficient if that's the case?

Comment: So then if its not performance, its just being comfortable in the syntax.

Comment: You can also use glob-style matching: `[[ "${fld[3]}" == *[GATC] ]]`

Comment: Thats pretty cool. Thanks @glennjackman, I didn't know that one. Always appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Huh... after the **excellent** Kent's `awk` solution am hesitating writing a long regexp :) :)

```
grep -P 'ATOM\s+\S+\s+\S+\s*\S*[GATC]\s+' dnafile
```

this need a grep with `-P` - perl regexes.

Without perl regexes, the stndard-regex is much longer,

```
grep  'ATOM  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ]*[GATC]  *' dnafile
```

Comment: Can i use either in bash?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^ATOM.{15}[GATC]/w newfile' oldfile
```

Since columns may be empty, the match must be made on position in the line.

Comment: Can i use sed in bash?